# theme_pager to modify drupal pagination

Tags: drupal

I have the following theme_pager function inside template.php. The problem is , the "showing 1-25 of 200" gets displayed after each page number. How do i get it to display just once at the top.

```
function themename_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, $element = 0, $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9) {
  global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;
  $tags = array("", "< prev", "", "next >", "");

    // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
    // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
    $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
    // current is the page we are currently paged to
    $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
    // first is the first page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
    $pager_first = $pager_current - $pager_middle + 1;
    // last is the last page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
    $pager_last = $pager_current + $quantity - $pager_middle;
    // max is the maximum page number
    $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
    // End of marker calculations.

    // Prepare for generation loop.
    $i = $pager_first;
    if ($pager_last > $pager_max) {
    // Adjust "center" if at end of query.
    $i = $i + ($pager_max - $pager_last);
    $pager_last = $pager_max;
     }
    if ($i <= 0) {
    // Adjust "center" if at start of query.
    $pager_last = $pager_last + (1 - $i);
    $i = 1;
    }
    // End of generation loop preparation.
    $view = views_get_current_view();

    // ensure view exists
    if (!$view) return;

    // set object property to return total rows  
    $view->get_total_rows = true;



    // set display_id
    $view->set_display($display_id);

    // execute view
    $view->execute();

    // acquire data from views object and $_REQUEST    
    $itemsPerPage = $view->pager['items_per_page'];
    $currentPage = $_REQUEST['page']+1;
    $total = $view->total_rows;

    // start calculation    
    $start = 25*$currentPage-24;
    $end = $itemsPerPage * $currentPage;

    if ($end>$total) $end = $total;

    // return html
    $x =  "<center>Displaying $start - $end of $total</center>";
    $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('‹ previous')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
    $li_next = theme('pager_next', (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('next ›')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);

    if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {

      if ($li_previous) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => 'pager-previous',
        'data' => $li_previous,
      );
      }

    // When there is more than one page, create the pager list.
    if ($i != $pager_max) {
      // Now generate the actual pager piece.
      for (; $i <= $pager_last && $i <= $pager_max; $i++) {
        if ($i < $pager_current) {
          if ($pager_first > 1 && $i == $pager_first) {
              $output = '...'.$i;
              $stopPreEllipsis = true;
          } else {
              $output = $i;
          }
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => 'pager-item',
            'data' => theme('pager_previous', $output, $limit, $element, ($pager_current - $i), $parameters),
          );
        }
        if ($i == $pager_current) {
          $items[] = array(
            'class' => 'pager-current',
            'data' => $i,
          );
        }
        if ($i > $pager_current) {

          if ($pager_last < $pager_max && $i == $pager_last) {
              $output = $i.'...';
          } else {
              $output = $i;
          }

          $items[] = array(
            'class' => 'pager-item',
            'data' => theme('pager_next', $output, $limit, $element, ($i - $pager_current), $parameters),
          );
          $items[] = array(
           'class' => 'pager',
           'data' => $x,
          );
        }
      }
    }
    // End generation.
    if ($li_next) {
      $items[] = array(
        'class' => 'pager-next',
        'data' => $li_next,
      );
    }

    return theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ul', array('class' => 'pager'));
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines:

```
$items[] = array(
  'class' => 'pager',
  'data' => $x,
);
```

And return `$x` before the list of pager items like this (change the last line):

```
return $x . theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ul', array('class' => 'pager'));
```